# Telegram: Can a bot write a message to a specific user in a group?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I have a telegram group with several human members and a bot. This bot sends regular status updates to the group. I do this with a simple curl command.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MYBOT-ID>/sendMessage?chat_id=<MYCHAT-ID>=&text=hello%20world
```

Is there a possibility that the bot sends a message to a **specific user in the group**, e.g. to inform about a failure. The other members of the group should of course not see or hear this.

Comment: You can send the person a DM if there exists a prior interaction(chat) between the person and the bot. Other than that, I don't think such a way exists to change the visibility of specific messages

Answer (score 1):

You can use "user_id" instead of "chat_id" to send the message to the PV of users instead of sending message in the group

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MYBOT-ID>/sendMessage?chat_id=<USER-ID>=&text=hello%20world
```